# How to filter a gulp watch, which watches for CSS changes, in order to let browserSync stream only the actual modified files

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

I have a gulp watch task:

```
 gulp.watch([
        basePath+'/css/**/*.css'
    ], ['css']);
```

This task listens to changes of css files and starts the **"css"** task.

The css task, uses browserSync to stream the changes:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
        browserSync = require('browser-sync');

    gulp.task('css', function() {
        return gulp.src(basePath+'/css/**/*.css', {'read': false})
            .pipe(browserSync.stream());
    });
```

The problem is, **when I change only 1 css file**, browserSync see's all the css files in the folder (due to gulp.src) and, using web-sockets, streams the changes in the browser for all the files.

```
[BS] 3 files changed (custom.css, custom2.css, main.css)
```

This happens even if I change only custom2.css

Now, the question:

How to filter the gulp watch, or CSS task, in order to let browserSync stream only the actual modified files? and not all of them...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke [gulp.watch() with a glob and callback](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpwatchglob-opts-cb) and use the event passed to the callback to know exactly which css file changed.

```
gulp.watch(basePath+'/css/**/*.css', function(event) {
  gulp.src(event.path, {read: false})
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

After changing your watch to this, the css task in your example wouldn't be needed.